# Django doesn't see urls.py

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I'm following this tutorial: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

When I run the server with `python manage.py runserver`, it seems to work fine showing me no errors.
However when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/` it gives me the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in tutorial.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, snippets/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Here's my urls.py located in the tutorial folder:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('snippets.urls')),
]
```

I don't understand what's going on, how come it only checks `admin/` if I'm wiring the root urlconf to `snippets.urls`?

On a related note, when I modify `urls.py` and add gibberish the server won't give me an error, however if I were to modify `models.py` then it'll start complaining, that's why I'm getting the feeling it doesn't even check my `urls.py` and maybe instead some default one...

Any tips are very appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's my urls.py located in the snippets folder:

```
from django.urls import path
from snippets import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('snippets/', views.snippet_list),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.snippet_detail),
]
```

In settings.py I've only modified the INSTALLED_APPS part with the two last apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
]
```

Comment: Can you add your urls.py from your snippets app? Also did you register correctly your app in settings.py ?

Comment: @Guillaume Done! I added some more info at the end!

Comment: well that's weird ... How is it possible that it offers admin when it's not even in your URL list..? hmm.. it can be a clue to start..

Comment: Can you share the view and template related to the `snipppet_list`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have another instance of Django running?

That's the only thing I can think of since `admin` isn't even in your current urls