# Local server won't go through my URL pattern on my local server

Tags: django, url, localhost, django-urls, url-pattern

I'm new to Django and I'm facing a problem that I can't solve despit my research... I'v already made small django projects without this error but since I reformat my computer (I can't see the link but that's context!) i'm having this problem.

So when I'm running a django project this is what my browser shows me despite others urls in my project
[Django doesn't go trhough my urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2900p.png)

I'v tried with an almost empty project but a least one more url and still have the same page.

urls.py in the main file (src/mynotes/urls.py):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', include('dbnotes.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

settings.py in the main project (src/mynotes/settings.py):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dbnotes'
]
```

urls.py in the app (src/dbnotes/urls.py):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
]
```

views.py in the app (src/dbnotes/views.py):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def homepage(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Even stranger, when i change "path('admin/', admin.site.urls)" I still get the admin page with the same route. Even if i change 'admin/' or admin.site.urls.

It looks like my local server display an over empty django project but in the error page it's written "mynotes.urls" as the url location which is the good folder.

I'm working with a virtual environment.

I'm lost as it's the first time i got this issue despite having created ohter (small) django projects!

If anyone has an idea that would be great! Thank you!

The directory:
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw0GO.png)

I tried to follow the django documentation to write the smaller project and then having less room to error!
I tried with a new project and a new  virtual envirnoment.
I found a topic related to my problem but without an anwer : [Django doesn't see urls.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67424421/django-doesnt-see-urls-py)

Comment: Have you added the "dbnotes" app the `installed_apps` in setting.py file ??

Comment: @KingWealth, thank you for your answer. Yes I did, its in the second code quote of the question.

Comment: do u have `__init__.py` file in src/dbnotes/ directory?

Comment: @kalkidanTeklu Yes, it's inside, I added a picture of the directory.

Comment: Try modifying urls.py like this in the main file (src/mynotes/urls.py):

`from dbnotes.urls import urlpatterns as dbnotesurls`
`urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', include(dbnotesurls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]`

Comment: Hi @SourabhBurse! So it looks like this after modification but it still only goes through admin/ (like in the first image of my post) `from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from dbnotes.urls import urlpatterns as dbnotesurls

urlpatterns = [     
path('index/', include(dbnotesurls)),     
path('admin/', admin.site.urls), ]`

Comment: Django and python version?
It is strange, I just tried doing the same thing and it is working fine in workspace.
Can you please confirm that you are running the server from your virtualenv.

Comment: @SourabhBurse, Python is 3.11.0 and Django 4.1.3, yes I confirm that I am running the server from an env. And same the same code works on an other computer! It just looks like the localserver displays an other empty django project

Comment: @VincentAb If this is the case then have you tried to runserver on any other port?
`python manage.py runserver 7000`

Comment: So… I think I found the solution and it’s actually really disappointing. For some reason VSCode wasn’t editing anymore my files. I was modifying the project in VS but the actual files were not changing. I don’t know what to say ^^. Anyway thank you very much for your time